# Remove group of values if any of the values are greater than X

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to be able to remove a group of rows (using group_by) based on one or more of the cells within that group being less than X (say 7 for this example)

I have the following example data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(
  group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  .Names = c("group_id", "value"),
  row.names = c(NA, -9L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

output:

| group_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

I want to remove any of the groups (as grouped by group_id) which contain at least one 'value' cell above 7, so it would look like this:

| group_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

So group 3 is removed as it contained 1 or more values over 7

I have used the following code, but it isn't removing line 7 (group_id = 3, value = 7)

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  filter(value <7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could wrap with `any`

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  filter(!any(value > 7), .by = group_id)
```

-output

```
  group_id value
1        1     1
2        1     2
3        1     3
4        2     4
5        2     5
6        2     6
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(group_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), value = 1:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I had tried wrapping with !any but had used [] instead of () to wrap! Doh. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  group_by(group_id) |> 
  # add a variable to see if the condition is satisfied
  mutate(check_filter = if_else(value < 7, TRUE, NA)) |> 
  # apply that condition to the other rows for that id
  fill(check_filter) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  filter(check_filter) |> 
  select(-check_filter)
```